# How to save txt file with UTF-16 LE BOM encoding in Python

Tags: python, byte-order-mark, utf-16le

I have files encoded with UTF16 LE BOM encoding and need to alter them and save.
However I could not see such encoding option in
https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

My code:

```
with open("file.txt", mode='w', encoding="utf_16_le") as file:
    content = file.read()
    function_to_replace_content(content)
    file.write(content)
```

This saves the file without BOM. Is there an option to encode the file including BOM and save it that way?

Similar questions here didn't have quite explanatory and/or working answers.

Comment: Explicitly write a `"\uFEFF"` character to the file after opening it.

Comment: Use `utf16`. It always adds a BOM when writing and removes it when reading

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got this pretty quick after all:

```
# Saves a file in fpath containing content using selected encoding
def save_file_contents(fpath, content, encoding, bom=None):
    with open(fpath, mode='w', encoding=encoding) as fout:
        if bom:
            fout.write(u'\ufeff')
        fout.write(content)
        print('Processed', fpath)

save_file_contents(fpath, content, 'utf-16-LE', bom=True)
```